# Install fails, Grub already installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 20.04 dual booted with Windows 10 already working.  The computer shop had put a different version of Ubuntu on the machine instead of leaving space for me to install.  I repartioned the drive and made more space and now am attempting to install the current Ubuntu LTS version.  I can boot into Ubuntu from the USB install drive and can even use Gpart but when I select install the process hangs
I suspect that I have the wrong version of GRUB existing on the machine but I am exactly out of ideas how to fix the machine. I have 1 TB of unallocated space on the HDD but I never get past the step where I select Install.

Comment: UEFI boot for the record.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair